# Customize Test Name in Xunit2

Tags: .net, xunit2

When I run my tests today with xUnit v2, I typically use a naming convention like:

`[Fact(DisplayName= "Method Will Do Something")]
  public void Method_Will_Do_Something() { }`

What extensibility point can I plug into that will allow me set my test display name based on the naming conventions of my test method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way: Custom fact attribute, discoverer, and test case.

Example: https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/tree/master/RetryFactExample

For your custom test case, derive from `XunitTestCase` and override the `Initialize()` method. After calling `base.Initialize()`, set the `DisplayName` property appropriately.

You can see the default behavior for `XunitTestCase` here: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Frameworks/XunitTestCase.cs

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom class for your fact

```
public sealed class MyFactAttribute : FactAttribute
{
    public MyFactAttribute([CallerMemberName] string memberName = null)
    {
        DisplayName = memberName;
    }
}
```

And use as follows

```
[MyFact]
public void FileSystemProvider_Sync()
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thnx

Comment: thanks, Brad answer is also correct but I thought a very simple here is the code just copy and paste it would be helpful.